# How to change array based on tapped cell

Tags: ios, swift

In HomeViewController, I have 5 static collection view cells:
- Alkalinity, Calcium, Magnesium, Nitrate, Phosphate
When a user taps a cell, it navigates to Details View Controller, into a variable called `var dataReceived: Parameter?`
Parameter model is used in HomeViewController to define the product name.

What I need to do is:
- If alkalinity cell is tapped, VC B should have an array of Alkalinity Product ex: alk 1, alk2, alk3

- If a user taps calcium the array should be cal1 cal2 cal 3 and so on...

I tried using an enum and a switch statement.

```
MODEL
class Parameter {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name

    }
}

class Product {
    var element: Element?
    var name: [String]
    init(element: Element?, name: [String]) {
        self.element = element
        self.name = name
    }
}

enum Element {
    case alkalinity
    case calcium
    case magnesium
}

VCB START HERE
class DetailViewController: UITableViewController {
    var dataReceived : Parameter? // use this to get arrays the change
    var alkalinityProducts = ["Al1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = dataReceived?.name

    }
}
```

I need to find out how to update this, am I wrong with how I Modeled the data?

Comment: Is the problem in transfering data between controllers or with smth else? How do you open DetailViewController? Via segue or programmatically?

Comment: via segue. Data transfer between the controller works. Im just asking how to create my data so that I can have a different array based on what was tapped